# if else bash statement syntax

Tags: bash, shell-script

So for some reason, it always returns either ssh or 'ok' regardless of how I modify the test statement and have no idea what to do. I left the code below.

```
echo 'Wanna connect to the raspberry pi? (y/n)'
read $sssh

if [[ $sssh == "y" ]]
then 
        ssh pi@192.168.0.56
else 
        echo 'ok'
fi
```

Comment: and you expect it to return something else?

Comment: is this all on a single line?

Answer (score 0):

The `read` utility expects the name of a variable as its argument.  With `read $sssh`, you give it the value of the `sssh` variable rather than the name of a variable.

I'm assuming that you'd want to read into the `sssh` variable, in which case you should have used `read sssh`.

Your modified script (incorporating a read loop that iterates until valid input is given by the user):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -p 'Connect to RPi? (y/n): ' yesno
    case $yesno in
        y) ssh ...; break ;;
        n) echo ok; break ;;
        *) echo invalid input >&2
    esac
fi
```

or, longer,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -p 'Connect to RPi? (y/n): ' yesno
    if [[ $yesno == 'y' ]]; then
        ssh ...
        break
    elif [[ $yesno == 'n' ]]; then
        echo ok
        break
    fi
    echo invalid input >&2
fi
```

Comment: Also beware that the behaviour of `read` is dependant on the current value of the `$IFS` variable, so it's good practice to always set `IFS` for its invocation. You'll probably want to pass `-r` as well unless you have a good reason for it to treat backslashes specially. So `IFS= read -rp ...`. See also `zsh` and its `read -q` for yes/no questions.